# Automate integration Jenkins with Azure AD using openid connect plugin in jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, azure-active-directory

I have integrated jenkins with Azure AD manually and its working fine. However i am looking for some kind of script(maybe groovy) which it does this for me automatically. 
If not Alternatively is there a way if i can use web api through curl/wget post methods ?

[image]

I am trying with this script

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.tools.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.plugins.*
import hudson.security.SecurityRealm.*


def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
String clientId = 'xxxx'
String clientSecret = 'xxxxxx'
String tokenServerUrl = 'https//login.xxxxxx'
String authorizationServerUrl = 'https//login.xxxxxxx'
String userInfoServerUrl = ''
String userNameField = 'sub'
String tokenFieldToCheckKey = ''
String tokenFieldToCheckValue = ''
String fullNameFieldName = 'name'
String emailFieldName = 'email'
String scopes = 'openid email profile'
String groupsFieldName = ''
boolean disableSslVerification = 'false'
boolean logoutFromOpenidProvider = 'false'
String endSessionUrl = ''
String postLogoutRedirectUrl = ''
boolean escapeHatchEnabled = 'false'
String escapeHatchUsername = ''
String escapeHatchSecret = ''
String escapeHatchGroup = ''


adrealm = new OicSecurityRealm(clientId, clientSecret, tokenServerUrl, authorizationServerUrl, userInfoServerUrl, userNameField, tokenFieldToCheckKey, tokenFieldToCheckValue, fullNameFieldName, emailFieldName, scopes, groupsFieldName, disableSslVerification, logoutFromOpenidProvider, endSessionUrl, postLogoutRedirectUrl, escapeHatchEnabled, escapeHatchUsername, escapeHatchSecret, escapeHatchGroup)

instance.setSecurityRealm(adrealm)
```

This is the error i am getting.

**Run Result**
`org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script1.groovy: 28: unable to resolve class OicSecurityRealm 
 @ line 28, column 11.
   adrealm = new OicSecurityRealm(clientId, clientSecret, tokenServerUrl, authorizationServerUrl, userInfoServerUrl, userNameField, tokenFieldToCheckKey, tokenFieldToCheckValue, fullNameFieldName, emailFieldName, scopes, groupsFieldName, disableSslVerification, logoutFromOpenidProvider, endSessionUrl, postLogoutRedirectUrl, escapeHatchEnabled, escapeHatchUsername, escapeHatchSecret, escapeHatchGroup)
             ^`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding this line. 
`import org.jenkinsci.plugins.oic.*`

Answer (score 0):

```
import hudson.model.*
import jenkins.model.*
import hudson.tools.*
import hudson.security.*
import hudson.plugins.*
import hudson.security.SecurityRealm.*
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.oic.*


def instance = Jenkins.getInstance()
String clientId = ''
String clientSecret = ''
String wellKnownOpenIDConfigurationUrl = ''
String tokenServerUrl = ''
String authorizationServerUrl = ''
String userInfoServerUrl = ''
String userNameField = 'username'
String tokenFieldToCheckKey = ''
String tokenFieldToCheckValue = ''
String fullNameFieldName = 'displayName'
String emailFieldName = 'email'
String scopes = 'openid email profile'
String groupsFieldName = 'tokenGroups'
boolean disableSslVerification = false
Boolean logoutFromOpenidProvider = false
String endSessionEndpoint = ''
String postLogoutRedirectUrl = ''
boolean escapeHatchEnabled = false
String escapeHatchUsername = ''
String escapeHatchSecret = ''
String escapeHatchGroup = ''
String automanualconfigure = ''


adrealm = new OicSecurityRealm(clientId, clientSecret, wellKnownOpenIDConfigurationUrl, tokenServerUrl, authorizationServerUrl, userInfoServerUrl, userNameField, tokenFieldToCheckKey, tokenFieldToCheckValue, fullNameFieldName, emailFieldName, scopes, groupsFieldName, disableSslVerification, logoutFromOpenidProvider, endSessionEndpoint, postLogoutRedirectUrl, escapeHatchEnabled, escapeHatchUsername, escapeHatchSecret, escapeHatchGroup, automanualconfigure)

instance.setSecurityRealm(adrealm)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).